# Use hyperlink for tree objects

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

Can i use hyperlink to my treeobject. I have four nodes in my tree. i want each each node to be hyperlinked. Is this possible in Eclipse Rcp? Help is needed. Sample code will be useful. I have used the rcp mail Template.

Comment: Can you please paste the code you have so far. It's not impossible.

Comment: @darijan I have used the RCP Mail Template. In the left navigation panel you can see tree nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom tree node and store the link as a data object in the tree node. Then add a selection listener to the tree. When any of the tree node is selected you will get an event from which you can extract the data object and use the information to open a new view or anything elese that you want to do.